# Merge multiple text files over unique rows of lines

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have several files in a folder containing text (alphabet, numbers, symbol, etc.). I want to find the lines that are not present in all the files i.e. if a line is present in all the text files, it must be excluded. If a line is present in only 1 or at max N-1 files then it must be included in the merged file with the name of all the files where it is present.

PS: The files are not identical, can have more or less number of lines. Lines present in all the files (irrespective of their locations) must be excluded.

So, as an example:

```
FILE1:
<abc> 123
$def 456$

FILE2:
$def 456$
ghi 789

FILE3:
$def 456$
ghi 789
```

.
.
.

```
MERGED FILE:
<abc> 123 ==> FILE1
ghi 789 ==> FILE2, FILE3
```

Comment: What have you done in an attempt solve this? Also, why have you attached so many tags?

Comment: Did you... try anything?

Comment: I am new to programming and stack overflow. I have a logic like: read each line of each file, and match it in the remaining files. If you don't find in any of the files then add it to the merged file.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Is this a homework problem?  Are you trying to learn a programming language?  Is this part of some larger task?  What task?

Comment: I'm stuck in my thought process, what could be an efficient way of doing such tedious task. I've read about merge sort, but this is a bit different task. Also, I can't use commands like "comm" or "sort". Is there anything precooked on such problems. It's part of my homework, any utility/tool is ok with me. I just created this problem myself and unfortunately not able to solve it using a computer.

Comment: Are lines which have identical content in all files but different line numbers to be included or excluded? Sample looks like excluded. But finding identical lines on always the same line number is much easier than checking whether they are anywhere (nearby). There are tools (some of them for money) doing so and they are not trivial.

Comment: Is sorting the input files before processing OK? That would of course change the order of lines in the merged file, too.

Comment: @Yunnosch: No, lines present in all the files (irrespective of their locations) must be excluded. The files are not identical, can have more or less number of lines. Sorting is OK, but lines can contain all possible valid characters.

Comment: And is sorting OK?

Comment: yes, sorting is fine.

Comment: Do the files have UNIX line endings? Then try how close this gets you: `grep -Ff"File1.txt" File2.txt | grep -Ff- File3.txt | grep -Frvf- .`

Comment: Close enogh, the output is something like this:

`./File2.txt:ghi 789
./File3.txt:ghi 789
./File1.txt:FILE1:
./File1.txt:<abc> 123`

Comment: Something like this: `<abc> 123 ==> FILE1
ghi 789 ==> FILE2, FILE3`

Also, I want to understand how you do it? and how can i extend it to N number of files?

Comment: Forget my grep idea. It is awful for many files. Check out the cool answers, but make the authors explain theme in detail. ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much Yunnosch.

Comment: Don't spam multiple language tags.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: I'm new to this platform, my question wasn't language specific. I figured out that these languages/commands (tagged above) are most appropriate for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge.pl

```
my(%file,%line,@f);
chomp, ++$file{$ARGV}, ++$line{$_}{$ARGV} while <>;
(@f=keys(%{$line{$_}}))==keys(%file) or print "$_ ==> ".join(",",sort@f)."\n"
    for sort keys %line;
```

Then run:

```
perl merge.pl dir/FILE*
```

---

#### Restyled Perl code

```
my (%file, %line);

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    ++$file{$ARGV};
    ++$line{$_}{$ARGV};
}

for my $key ( sort keys %line ) {

    my @f = keys %{ $line{$key} };
    
    if ( @f < keys %file ) {
        print "$_ ==> ", join(",", sort @f), "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG.  :) Although, it outputs on the console. How you do it I want to know.

`<abc> 123 ==> File1.txt
ghi 789 ==> File2.txt,File3.txt`

Also, I'll update the code find a merged file

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you laid out your code tidily. This isn't a golfing competition.

Comment: Cool code. But without explanation not a good StackOverflow answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch: It is not "cool" to post obfuscated code in an effort to impress people.

Comment: This solution doesn't correctly handle lines that appear multiple times in one file.

Comment: @Borodin I totally agree. That is actually what I wanted to express. "Cool" is not helpful. My comment also was kind of obfuscated. My bad.

Comment: @all: Thanks for the efforts. But teach me something as well through explanations. I want to learn as well.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I've reformatted it and added a readable version which shows that it's not so clever after all.

Comment: "This solution doesn't correctly handle lines that appear multiple times in one file". I think it does. (Dont be confused by ++, its not about counting, just about registering existence)  And I cannot see anything in the original post about how to handle lines that appear multiple times in one file.

Comment: It works fine with my file(X).txt(s) mentioned above and even if I copy a line multiple times in a file it excludes it only if that is present in all the files.

Comment: Some explanation, but I don't think this code to be so complex that it deserves this much commentary, just reading the perl code should be enough here: The while(<>) loops through all lines in all files on the command line. The $ARGV variable contains the current file name. The %file hash is used to find the number of files. The %line hash (it's really a hash of hashes) registers which files a line exists in. The for loops through all unique lines. The @f inside is a list of the files that the current line exists in. If that number of files is less than all the files, those will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Perl:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $num_files = 0;
my %lines;
for my $fn ( <FILE*> ) {
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        next if $line =~ /^\s*$/;
        push @{ $lines{$line} }, $fn;
    }
    close $fh;
    $num_files++;
}

for my $line (keys %lines) {
    my @files = @{ $lines{$line} };
    if ( @files < $num_files ) {
        say $line, ' ==> ', join ",", @files;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
ghi 789 ==> FILE2,FILE3
<abc> 123 ==> FILE1
```

Comment: I don't see any output or new merged file created.

Comment: `next if $line =~ /^\s*$/` is clearer as `next unless $line =~ /\S/`, and it's even neater if you keep the line in `$_` and use `next unless /\S/` etc.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the comment. I agree it is neater and clearer. But it is still readable (to me at least) as it is, and I am lazy and prefer not to optimize/polish before it is really necessary.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for the comment, but I have another approach: The code does not use any *"special tricks"*. A good programming principle is to avoid excessive comments and try make the code self explanatory when given good variable names and good structure. Then, do only comment things that may not be immediately obvious to a reader.

Comment: There is writing maintainable code and there is writing a StackOverflow answer. The audience is different, so should the level of explanation be. Explaining in prose would allow to keep your style of comment-free programming. If you are interested in my style of commenting: I write comments in order to ensure that the most stupid imaginable colleague (still being paid by our common employer) can immediatly understand the code. That most stupid imaginable colleague is me - after a three week holiday.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: `next unless /\S/` is neither optimisation nor polish: it 8s simply easier to write and to read. Ideal for lazy people!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and ARGIND:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ lines[$0][FILENAME] }
END {
    for (line in lines) {
        if ( length(lines[line]) != ARGIND ) {
            printf "%s ==> ", line
            c = 0
            for (file in lines[line]) {
                printf "%s%s", (c++ ? ", " : ""), file
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
ghi 789 ==> file2, file3
<abc> 123 ==> file1
```